# c# Find index of curly brace in string

Tags: c#

> **Update:** The code works, error was caused by something else.

How do you find the index of a curly brace ({) in a string? I keep getting `-1` even though the curly brace is there. Here's my code;

```
var str = "example string with {brace}.";
var index = str.IndexOf("{");
```

I've tried escaping the brace like this

```
var index = str.IndexOf("{{");
```

and like this

```
var index = str.IndexOf("{{}");
```

but it still returns `-1`

Comment: What version of C# is the project targeting?

Comment: @TiesonT., the error was caused by something else. I've updated the question. Thnaks

Comment: I'm voting to close my own question as there was no problem with the code. Turned out a previous line in real code was truncating the line before the brace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've posted works just fine. Tested in LinqPad

```
var str = "example string with {brace}.";
var index = str.IndexOf("{");
```

returns `20`.

There is no need to try and escape the `{` character. If you're for sure getting back -1 you have a different problem and will probably need to post more information/code for it to be resolved.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Brainfart moment! It was something else. Thanks.

Comment: np, happens to everyone

Comment: @MosesMachua it is usually a noble thing to accompany an accepted answer with upvoting. I am sure you are at 1.7k+ because so many do follow that. Anyway, thank me I am upvoting this deserved answer for you so a noble practice is performed.

Comment: @MukeshAdhvaryu done!

Comment: @MosesMachua thanks. This proves that Stackoverflow is not about strategic voting and downvoting retribution tactics. We are here for the cause.